# How to Increase the radius of a circle using Coord_polar()

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have a doughnut sort of plot which i plot using the ggplot2. Code was shared by @Jonspring.

```
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
       Tenure.Type = c("Tenure_A","Tenure_B",
                       "Tenure_C","Tenure_D","Tenure_E"),
        In.Poverty = c(45786L, 98453L, 34954L, 29586L, 74854L),
    Not.in.Poverty = c(784733L, 359584L, 385884L, 948434L, 385869L)
) -> Poverty

library(tidyverse)
Poverty %>%
  pivot_longer(-Tenure.Type) %>%
  uncount(round(value/1000)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(1, name, color = Tenure.Type)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  coord_polar()
```

This is what i got -

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkkPA.png)

I was wondering if there is any way to increase the size/surface area of the outer ring while keeping the inner ring as it is. Thanks.

I tried using the agruments inside the Coord_polar() but I can't get it to work.

Note - If you can notice, in the plot each dot represents 1000 observations. So, is there something in which we can achieve like each outer ring's dot represents 10,000 observations and each inner ring's dot represent 1,000 observations? Thanks.

Comment: That's, technically, possible. Only that the viewer will probably hardly learn much from the visualisation other than that there are impoverished people among each tenure track. To what extent, and which track is most impacted has to be explained by the speaker. A simple barplot with percentage of impoverished by track might serve the purpose much better, even (and because) plain and familiar to the audience.

Comment: There is a fixed space from the radius axis' limits to the outermost line that can't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split those 2 categories between separate jitter layers and play around with jitter heights to achieve something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Poverty %>%
  pivot_longer(-Tenure.Type) %>%
  uncount(round(value/1000)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(1, name, color = Tenure.Type, shape = name)) +
  geom_jitter(data = ~filter(.x, name == "Not.in.Poverty" ), height = .6) +
  geom_jitter(data = ~filter(.x, name == "In.Poverty" ), height = .35) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    name = "Scale",
    values = c("Not.in.Poverty" = 15, "In.Poverty" = 19), 
    labels = c("Not.in.Poverty" = "n=10000", "In.Poverty" = "n=1000")
    )+
  coord_polar()
```

[image]

Input data:

```
Poverty <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Tenure.Type = c("Tenure_A","Tenure_B",
                  "Tenure_C","Tenure_D","Tenure_E"),
  In.Poverty = c(45786L, 98453L, 34954L, 29586L, 74854L),
  Not.in.Poverty = c(784733L, 359584L, 385884L, 948434L, 385869L)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>